# Automate auto-complete of the import line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm following a React tutorial and the instructor has a VSCode plugin that generates an import line as you type. Example:

When typing:

```
 <time>{formatISO9075(new Date(createdAt))}</time>
```

Automatically generates this line at the top of the document.

```
import {formatISO9875} from "date-fn";
```

I would like to know how to do it.
The instructor didn't go into detail about the plugin he uses.

For more details, see the images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you have the javascript/typescript extension installed?

Comment: No. I dont't have it installed.

Comment: Can you install that and try again

Comment: Is this extension 'JavaScript and Typescript Nightly'?

Comment: The one without the `Nightly`